# Simple JSP expression language code won't work

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

I have a Person class and Dog class. Person has-a dog. I send a `post http request` to a servlet from a simple html file. In the servlet, I add a person with his dog as an attribute to the request. The servlet forwards this request to a jsp which should print the name of the dog using expression language or EL.

I followed all the instructions in my book and I am getting the wrong output. Please 
help me to fix my code.

Expected output - Dog's name is: dog.
Actual output - Dog's name is:

**Servlet's doPost -**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Person p = new Person();
    Dog d = new Dog();

    p.setName("Man");
    d.setName("dog");

    request.setAttribute("person", p);

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/MyJsp.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);

}
```

**JSP main code -**

```
<html>
<body>
Dog's name is: ${person.dog.name}
</body>
</html>
```

**Full code for Pojos and stacktrace -**

Dog-

```
package foo;

public class Dog {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

}
```

Person -

package foo;

public class Person {

```
String name;
Dog dog;

public String getName() {return name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public Dog getDog() {return dog;}
public void setDog(Dog dog) {this.dog = dog;}

}
```

I restarted eclipse and tomcat again and my code worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set a dog for the person.

```
p.setDog(d);
```

Comment: oh ! duh. Why does'nt it give me a null exception to make my life easy.

Comment: Now I get the error - `HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'dog' not found on type foo.Person`. But I set the dog object for this person.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Is the getter named `getDog` and the setter named `setDog`?

Comment: yes it is. I rebuilt my project and restarted eclipse and tomcat to be sure. I still get the exception.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Can you post your POJOs and the full stack trace in your question?

Comment: Thanks. I restarted eclipse again and it works. Why ? I knew I could not have made a mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Person` class will need public setter and getter `Dog` methods.  Your `Dog` class will need public setter and getter `Name` methods

E.g.

```
 public class Person { ...

     private Dog dog;

     public Dog getDog () {return dog;} 

     .....
```

Comment: yes, it was all there. I did forget to add dog to person in my servlet which was dumb, but the 500 error confused me. It goes when you restart eclipse twice. Who would have guessed ?